# Forcing Protobuf.js to ignore unrecognized JS-side fields

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers

In sending objects back and forth between JS (TypeScript actually) and .NET w/ protobuf.js I would like to decorate the JS objects w/ fields only meaningful at runtime (e.g. WebGL context, handles, etc.).  Adding a new dynamic field is straightforward:

```
ReceivedObject.RuntimeField = new RuntimeField();
```

However, when serializing back up to the server protobuf.js discovers the new field and throws an exception.

I have found I can hack around this by adding the three lines below directly to protobuf.js:

```
MessagePrototype.set = function (keyOrObj, value, noAssert) {
    if (keyOrObj && typeof keyOrObj === 'object') {
        noAssert = value;
        for (var ikey in keyOrObj)
            if (keyOrObj.hasOwnProperty(ikey) && typeof (value = keyOrObj[ikey]) !== 'undefined') {
                if (ikey == "RuntimeField") {   // added
                    continue;                   // added    
                }                               // added
                this.$set(ikey, value, noAssert);
            }
        return this;
    }
    ...
}
```

This is of course not very maintainable.  Is there a better approach?  The object hierarchy is rich and deep so I'd like to avoid approaches involving wholesale copying of 100s of fields to/from custom JS-side objects.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a short example for you. You can solve this problem using `Object.defineProperty` to add a non-enumerable property (this won't show up when you use `for (var key in obj)`.

In the example below, the `first` property is enumerable (and will appear in the console window along with the `name` property). The `second` property is not enumerable, so it won't appear in the console window.

Using this technique, you could add properties that won't be picked up in your `for` loop.

```
var obj = {
    name: 'Steve'
};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'first', {
  enumerable: true,
  value: 'example'
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'second', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: 'example'
});

for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) 
        && typeof (value = obj[key]) !== 'undefined') {

        console.log(key);   
    }
}
```

So to tie this back to your specific question, you could use...

```
Object.defineProperty(ReceivedObject, 'RuntimeField', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: new RuntimeField()
});
```